# Is there a way of opening the default app screen for a specific group (home app, phone app) using intent?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I have already tried using this intent constructor, but it does not work properly. This is a launcher application so I'd like to open the home app item.

```
Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package", M3_LAUNCHER_PKG, null);
return new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_DEFAULT_APPS_SETTINGS).setData(uri);
```

Comment: Can you provide an example? I didn't get the question.

Comment: Using this intent on Android 24 or greater I can access the third screen from this [image](https://www.androidguys.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/01-Main.jpg), but I would like to redirect the user to this [screen](https://www.androidguys.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/Main-04.jpg).